# How to convert multidimensional list to numpy.array in order to fit in cv2.fillConvexPoly

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have a dictionary 'roi' as following,

```
{  
10: [],  
11: [[[315.0, 193.0],
   ... ...
   [315.0, 193.0]]],  
12: [[[317.0, 195.0],
   ... ...
   [317.0, 195.0]],
  [[318.0, 320.0],
   ... ...
   [318.0, 320.0]]],  
13: [[[307.0, 148.0],
   ... ...
   [307.0, 148.0]],
  [[311.0, 323.0],
   ... ...
   [311.0, 323.0]]],  
14: [[[306.0, 170.0],
    ... ...
   [306.0, 170.0]],
  [[322.0, 302.0],
   ... ...
   [322.0, 302.0]]],  
15: [[[303.0, 167.0],
   ... ...
   [303.0, 167.0]]],  
16: [[[301.0, 168.0],
   ... ...
   [301.0, 168.0]]],  
17: [[[302.0, 175.0],
   ... ...
   [302.0, 175.0]]],  
18: [[[299.0, 190.0],
   ... ...
   [299.0, 190.0]]]}  
}
```

What I am trying to do is using the lists in the dict as point sets , and applying cv2.fillConvexPoly to 'mask'

Since cv2.fillConvexPoly requires the input point sets to be of type numpy.array, I tried to convert the whole thing using np.array().

```
for k in roi.keys():
    point_sets = np.array(roi[k])
    for p in range(point_sets.shape[0]):
        print(type(point_sets[p]))
#       cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask[k], point_set, 1)
```

And the result is,

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

It occurs to me that because the lists corresponding to key 12, 13, and 14 happen to contain 2 lists, the 2 lists inside can't be converted to np.array in the first place. As a result, I worked on this problem by doing the type conversion twice by ascertaining everyone is of type np.array.

```
 point_sets = np.array(roi[k])
 for p in range(point_sets.shape[0]):
     point_set = np.int32([np.array(point_sets[p])])
     cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask[k], point_set, 1)
```

Now I am expecting some ways to do this without doing np.array() twice, since it appears a bit awkward and unnecessary.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the two lists are of the same size? Because if they are, `np.array` should be able to convert the list of lists into a one single giant numpy array. But if the are not, then it is impossible to make a single array out of them, and numpy would convert them into a numpy array of objects, and the objects are the two lists. To illustrate:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [3]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]])
Out[3]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6, 7])], dtype=object)
```

If this is the reason why your code fails, you may want to convert the list of lists into a list of numpy array, instead of an entire numpy array, to avoid the issue:

```
In [4]: [ np.array(x) for x in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]] ]
Out[4]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7])]
```